# Gson asking for Integer TypeAdapter

Tags: java, json, types, gson

I am trying to serialize/deserialize a quite big object (that's why I will not write the whole object here) from and to json using Gson.
I have created TypeAdapter to `DateTime` and `LocalDate` but it still goes wrong with exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: java.lang.Integer. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

But as I have read in Gson docs, Integer does not need a TypeAdapter so I have check all the inner-objects inside this looking for something which needs an adapter and I found these non-primitive types:

> Sets, List, Array, Enum

I have looked for them all and it seems like no one of these needs a TypeAdapter.

I am using this code to serialize the object:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            //these adapters are already tested and everything went right
            .registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new DateTimeJsonConverter())
            .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateJsonConverter())
            .create();

WStepWork returnValue = new WStepWorkBL().getStep(id, currentUserId);

String json = gson.toJson(returnValue);
```

Does anyone knows if I actually need a TypeAdapter for any of these four or what is possibly going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I have looking for the error and it's caused because of this:

model.java:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class WExternalMethod implements java.io.Serializable {

    //many attributes
    private String[] paramlistName;

    private Class[] paramlistType;  
}
```

mapping.hbm.xml:

```
<class name="org.beeblos.bpm.core.model.WExternalMethod" table="w_process_head_method">
    <property name="paramlistName"
            type="com.sp.hibernate.common.usertype.StringArrayUserType">
            <column name="paramlist_name">
                <comment>for APP synchro: parameter list to send</comment>
            </column>
        </property>
        <property name="paramlistType"
            type="com.sp.hibernate.common.usertype.ClassArrayUserType">
            <column name="paramlist_type">
                <comment>for APP synchro: parameter list types (java types)</comment>
            </column>
        </property>
</class>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve], which means you take your complicated object and reduce it to such a small object that only shows your error and doesn't contain any other stuff. And you also include the exact code that registers and serializes that object.

Comment: Totally forgot the code, sorry about that. But the object, I just don't know what is producing the error so I don't know what should I write here.

Comment: Start removing elements from that object one by one. Or half each time. You'll get down to the field that creates the problem. Please thoroughly read the link about [mcve].

Comment: That's a great idea. It will take long time so I might delay on answering, thanks btw

Comment: Can you step into the library in your debugger (open source?) and find the exact iteration/input line that is causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a missunderstood. It was asking for a TypeAdapter to Class and not to Integer so I did:

```
public class ClassJsonConverter implements JsonSerializer<Class>, JsonDeserializer<Class> {

    public ClassJsonConverter(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Class src, Type srcType, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        String str = src.getName();
        return new JsonPrimitive(str);
    }

    @Override
    public Class deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {

        Class returnValue = null; 
        try {
            String str = json.getAsString();
            returnValue = Class.forName(str);
            return returnValue;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            String mess = "deserialize(): " 
                    + (e.getMessage()!=null?". "+e.getMessage():"")
                    + (e.getCause()!=null?". "+e.getCause():"");
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```